# Error when passing IE version to Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I'm trying to pass a simple test to my Selenium grid, while specifying which version of IE to run the test on.

I've started my node like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.201:4444/grid/register -browserName="internet explorer",version=10.0,platform=WINDOWS -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\IEDriverServer.exe
```

I see the node register to the hub with version 10, looks OK.
Then I start my test like this:

```
IWebDriver driver;
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "internet explorer");
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "10.0");

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.168.1.201:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

But I get the error:

```
Result Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : Error forwarding the new session
cannot find : Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, browserName=internet explorer, version=10.0}]
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The test can run when I don't specify the IE version, so the issue must be there - what is failing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

When registering a node as a browser version, you have to surround the browser parameters set with quotation marks. My new node startup command is:

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\IEDriverServer.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -port 5555 -role node -hub http://192.168.1.201:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox, maxInstances=10, platform=ANY, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=internet explorer, version=10, platform=WINDOWS, maxInstances=10" -browser "browserName=chrome,version=ANY,maxInstances=10,platform=WINDOWS"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think browser version should be "10" without ".0":

```
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "10");
```

You also don't need to initialize DesiredCapabilities twice, and then change settings once again. You can just set them to correct values in [constructor](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/fa067c7b80f2e07270b7e36d2a01938aa3f33973/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/DesiredCapabilities.cs#L38), so 5 lines collapse into 1:

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities( "internet explorer", "10", new Platform(PlatformType.Windows) );
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the test still fails with the same error... it just can't seem to recognize that this IE node is version 10 for some reason.

Comment: I think it must be my node setup command, as the grid doesn't seem to be registering the version properly. Still trying to figure out why.